# Sri Rudram Verses — nilakantha, sadashivaya

Tags: scripture, vedas, rig-veda, yajur-veda, sama-veda

Is this verse from Sri Rudram actually present in the  Taittiriya Samhita? I could not able to find any such verse. Some people say that this verse is later interpolation.

oṃ namaste astu bhagavan
viśrveśrvarāya mahādevāya
tryambakāya tripurāntakāya
trikālāgnikālāya
kālāgnirudrāya nīlakaṇṭhāya mṛtyuṃjayāya
sarveśrvarāya sadāśivāya
śrīman mahādevāya namaḥ

Comment: It's traditionally recited as part of the Sri Rudram, but it's not part of the actual text of the Sri Rudram in the Taittiriya Samhita. I don't know where it's from.

Answer (score 1):

The śrī rudram as referred to nowadays consists of two parts viz. the namakam and the camakam.

The namakam is based on is based on the 11 anuvāka-s of Tāittirīya-saṁhitā́ 4.5 and the camakam is based on is based on the first 11 anuvāka-s of Tāittirīya-saṁhitā́ 4.7.

Note that the śrī rudram is not a 'vedic' chant, but rather a chant based on the parts of the Tāittirīya-saṁhitā́ given above. Extra mantra-s have been added.

The verse you are refering to "oṃ namaste astu bhagavan viśveśvarāya mahādevāya tryambakāya tripurāntakāya trikālāgnikālāya kālāgnirudrāya nīlakaṇṭhāya mṛtyuṃjayāya sarveśrvarāya sadāśivāya śrīman mahādevāya namaḥ" is not part of the original rudra-praśna or the rudrādhyāya. It is a later addition.

Want proof? Take a look for yourself on TITUS:

[image]

As we can see it ends with "dhehi tám" and immediately goes to "námo híraṇya-bāhave..."

References:

https://titus.uni-frankfurt.de/texte/etcs/ind/aind/ved/yvs/ts/ts.htm